# Azure traffic manager endpoint update fails with 'The resourceTargetId property is invalid or missing'

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager, az

I am trying to update an Azure Traffic Manager endpoint with the Azure CLI, I run the following code:

```
 az network traffic-manager endpoint update \
      --name ${ENDPOINT_NAME} \
      --profile-name ${PROFILE_NAME} \
      --resource-group ${RESOURCE_GROUP} \
      --type azureEndpoints \
      --endpoint-status enabled \
      --set targetResourceId=${INGRESS_IP_ID}
```

The values for those different flags were obtained by previous calls to `az network traffic-manager endpoint list` But trying to set the endpoint `targetResourceId` to a different resource fails with this error:

> Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: The
> 'resourceTargetId' property of endpoint 'we' is invalid or missing.
> The property must be specified only for the following endpoint types:
> AzureEndpoints, NestedEndpoints. You must have read access to the
> resource to which it refers.

I can say with absolute certainty that the endpoint I am trying to update is an AzureEndpoint, and the resource I am trying to set it to exists in the same location as the endpoint itself. I have looked through the documentation and tried to google for this error, but haven't found anything useful so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can produce this issue. Probably, you pass the [--target-resource-id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/traffic-manager/endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-traffic-manager-endpoint-update-optional-parameters) incorrectly. It should be a full resource Id instead of the resource name.

[image]

If you target a public IP as the endpoint, you can use the command to get the resource Id.

```
az network public-ip show --name <publicIPName> --resource-group <resourceGroupName> --query "id"
```

Comment: I did pass in the correct ID. it is a kubernetes IP and I get it with this command 
`az network public-ip list -o tsv --query "[?dnsSettings.domainNameLabel=='${DOMAIN_NAME_LABEL}'].ipConfiguration.id"` I print the resource ID as a way to debug this problem, and it looks a lot like what you have underlined in red.

Comment: Have you tried to add this in portal UI? It looks like you are using a specific kubernetes IP. I am using a normal Azure VM public IP.

Comment: Yes. I tried to set the endpoint in the Portal UI and it worked, which is why I am puzzled really.

Comment: I seem that you get the ipconfiguration Id instead of public IP id.  You could use `az network public-ip list -o tsv --query "[?dnsSettings.domainNameLabel=='${DOMAIN_NAME_LABEL}'].id"`

Comment: You were right. I checked the ID i had printed, and it was not something like `.../publicIPAddresses/...` but was `.../frontendIPConfigurations/...`